# Convert .caf audio file to .wav audio file swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have recorded audio and saved in .caf format in document directory. I need to convert the .caf to .wav file to upload the file to server. I researched and didn't get much input in swift. Please help me out to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try AudioKit?
Maybe you can use AKConverter https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKConverter.html